# Test passing.But Test List is Failing

Tags: telerik-test-studio

Some of my Scripts are very finely working when running as test.But When I run the test in test list.it's failing why am not understanding.please give assistance.
Test log:

### Overall Result: Pass

- Using .Net Runtime version: '4.0.30319.18052' for test
                   execution. Build version is '2013.1.709.0'.

  - Starting execution....
  - Detected a Silverlight Test. Setting EnableSilverlight=True

    - Detected custom code in test. Locating test assembly:
      TestProject(BA).dll.

  '08/09/2013 PM 06:04:53' - Assembly Found:

### ------------------------------------------------------------

'08/09/2013 PM 06:04:53' - Using 'InternetExplorer' version '10.0' as default browser.

- 'Pass' : 1. Navigate to :

'Pass' : 2. radmaskedtextbox: click with '5' offset action.

'Pass' : 3. radmaskedtextbox: type 'abc' text action.

'Pass' : 4. LeftClick on Item1Textboxview

'Pass' : 5. Type 'abc@#' into PasswordPasswordbox
'08/09/2013 PM 06:05:07' -

'Pass' : 6. Click RadBtnSignInRadbutton

'Pass' : 7. [Converting_Quote_CodedStep1] : LeftClick on CustomersTextblock, RequiresSilverlight=True

'Pass' : 8. Verify QuoteTextblock's Left side Equal 19

'Pass' : 9. [Converting_Quote_CodedStep3] : LeftClick on QuoteTextblock, RequiresSilverlight=True

'Pass' : 10. LeftClick on PARTContentPresenterContentpresenter
'08/09/2013 PM 06:05:29' -

'Pass' : 11. [Converting_Quote_CodedStep] : LeftClick on DropDownPartRadtogglebutton, RequiresSilverlight=True

'Pass' : 12. [Converting_Quote_to_Invoice_CodedStep] : radmenuitem: 'To Invoice' click action., RequiresSilverlight=True

'Pass' : 13. Click BtnPrintRadribbonbutton

'Pass' : 14. radwindow: 'Close' action.

'Pass' : 15. Click SaveCloseRadribbonbutton

'Pass' : 16. [Converting_Quote_CodedStep2] 
: LeftClick on InvoiceTextblock, RequiresSilverlight=True
'08/09/2013 PM 06:05:41' -

'Pass' : 17. LeftClick on BlueBicycleTextblock
'08/09/2013 PM 06:05:45' -

### 'Pass' : 18. Click BtnCloseRadribbonbutton

Am attaching Error msg

Failure Information: 
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   Exception thrown executing coded step: '[Add_New_Quote_CodedStep3] :
   LeftClick on PARTFooterCellBorderBorder, RequiresSilverlight=True'.InnerException:

```
ArtOfTest.Common.Exceptions.FindElementException: Element Not found!
FindExpression used: 

[automationid 'Exact' dtgProductAndServiceInvoice] AND [XamlTag 'Exact' radgridview]
[XamlPath 'Exact'     /border[name=PART_MasterGridContainer]/
grid[name=HierrarchyBackground]/
gridviewscrollviewer     [automationid=PART_ItemsScrollViewer]/
grid[name=PART_RootPanel]/
gridviewfooterrow[automationid=PART_FooterRow]
/border[name=PART_FooterRowBorder]/selectivescrollinggrid[0]/
datacellspresenter [name=PART_DataCellsPresenter]/ grid[0]/
itemspresenter[0]/gridviewcellspanel[0]/
gridviewfootercell[0]/border[name=PART_FooterCellBorder]]

 at ArtOfTest.Common.WaitSync.CheckResult(WaitSync wait,StringextraExceptionInfo,Object target)
```

at ArtOfTest.Common.WaitSync.For[T](Predicate`1 predicate, T target, Boolean invertCondition, Int32 timeout, WaitResultType errorResultType)

```
 at ArtOfTest.WebAii.Silverlight.VisualWait.ForExistsInternal
(Int32 timeout, Boolean invertCondition)

at ArtOfTest.WebAii.Silverlight.VisualWait.ForVisible(Int32 timeout)
```

at ArtOfTest.WebAii.TestTemplates.XamlElementContainer.Get(XamlFindExpression expr, Boolean waitOnElement, Int32 timeout)

at ArtOfTest.WebAii.TestTemplates.XamlElementContainer.Get(XamlFindExpression expr)
   at ArtOfTest.WebAii.TestTemplates.XamlElementContainer.Get[TControl](XamlFindExpression expr)
   at ArtOfTest.WebAii.TestTemplates.XamlElementContainer.Get[TControl](String[] clauses)
   at TestProject_BA_.Pages.BPage.SilverlightAppElement.get_PARTFooterCellBorderBorder() in d:\pranavi\TestProject(BA06)\Pages.g.cs:line 1808

at TestProject_BA_.Add_New_Quote.Add_New_Quote_CodedStep3() in d:\pranavi\TestProject(BA06)\4#Invoice\Add New Quote.tstest.cs:line

please see the attachments.

Comment: How is it failing? In your question, it shows every step as a Pass.

Comment: At 11th step it's failing. Dropdwn is not happening.

Comment: Have you double-checked the locator for the DropDownPartRadtogglebutton, to make sure it's identifying it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing a web application, as you know telerik tests the UI components based on the baseURL. There are 2 different locations for settings when you are running as a test(vs running as a testList). Cross verify the baseURL in both the settings section(if they are the same). As I can see the error is    Element Not found. Which might be coz, the associated baseURL for that element is different.